# Clustering of large text datasets with unknown number of clusters

Tags: clustering, references, natural-language, large-data

I have a list of hotel names which may or may not be correct, and with different spellings (such as '&' instead of 'and'). I want to use clustering in order to group the hotels with different spelling, but that are the same nonetheless.
I thought of using Affinity Propagation with levenshtein distance, but the dataset is too large for it to work (about 15k rows).I am not sure of on how many clusters there should be, but it could be further investigated. Can anyone give me some tip on what algorithm to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. You could look at the [silhouette score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) (Rousseeuw, 1987), which measures how similar an object is to its own cluster compared to other clusters (where the higher the score, the better the clustering configuration). Or you could use the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)), though this method has problems (see Schubert, 2023 for more information), and I would not recommend it. Another possible approach is cross-validation (CV). Though you would need to use something other than traditional CV, as clustering (e.g., k-means) is a type of unsupervised learning, so you would need to consider a version of CV applicable to unsupervised learning (or clustering more generally; e.g., Fu & Perry, 2020).

**References**

Fu, W., & Perry, P. O. (2020). Estimating the number of clusters using cross-validation. Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 29(1), 162-173.

Rousseeuw, P. J. (1987). Silhouettes: a graphical aid to the interpretation and validation of cluster analysis. Journal of computational and applied mathematics, 20, 53-65.

Schubert, E. (2023). Stop using the elbow criterion for k-means and how to choose the number of clusters instead. ACM SIGKDD Explorations Newsletter, 25(1), 36-42.